# WPF Customized TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, customization

I have to develop a customized tab control and decided to create it with WPF/XAML, because I planned to learn it anyway. It should look like this when it's finished:

[image: Target]

I made good progress so far, but there are two issues left:

1. Only the first/last tab item should have a rounded upper-left/bottom-left corner. Is it possible to modify the style of these items, similar to the way I did with the selected tab item?
2. The selected tab item should not have a border on its right side. I tried to accomplish this with z-index and overlapping, but the results were rather disappointing. Is there any other way to do this?

[image: Current]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.TestWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="TestWindow" Height="350" Width="500" Margin="5" Background="LightGray">
<Window.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="SelectedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0.965"/>
                <GradientStop Color="WhiteSmoke" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Border
                            Panel.ZIndex="50"
                            Margin="0,100,-1,0" 
                            Background="#FFAAAAAA"
                            BorderBrush="Gray"
                            CornerRadius="7,0,0,7"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <TabPanel
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                IsItemsHost="True" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border
                            Background="WhiteSmoke"
                            BorderBrush="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="7,7,7,0" >
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" 
                            Background="#FFAAAAAA"
                            CornerRadius="7,0,0,0"
                            BorderBrush="Gray"
                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                            Panel.ZIndex="50"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                >

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"             
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-2,0" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                                    Property="BorderBrush" 
                                    Value="{StaticResource SelectedBorderBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                                Property="Background" 
                                Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                                Property="CornerRadius" 
                                Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="_menuTabControl" TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="5">
        <TabItem Name="_tabItem1" Header="First Tab Item" ></TabItem>

        <TabItem Name="_tabItem2" Header="Second Tab Item" >
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="_tabItem3" Header="Third Tab Item" >
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Edit: Thanks to Vlad, I could fix the second problem with a gradient border brush. See updates XAML for the solution.

Edit: Vlad fixed the first problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the second problem, you should perhaps try to [remove the clipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx)? Beware however of the [possible issues](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/12/28/cliptoboundsmaybe/).

For the first problem, you should try [style trigger](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Property_Triggers) on property `IsSelected`. (Edit: I see, you are doing it exactly this way.) Have a look how this is implemented at the default template [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032.aspx). Note that they are using `ZIndex`, too.

**Edit**:
I found a workaround for your first/last tab problem. You need to use attached properties to designate the first/last tab:

In your TestWindow class you define attached property:

```
public static bool GetIsFirstTab(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFirstTabProperty);
}

public static void SetIsFirstTab(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
{
    obj.SetValue(IsFirstTabProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFirstTabProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFirstTab", typeof(bool),
               typeof(TestWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

Then, in your first tab you set this property:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        ...
/>
    ...
    <TabItem Name="_tabItem1" Header="First Tab Item"
             local:TestWindow.IsFirstTab="true">
    </TabItem>
```

Then, you should define a trigger for it:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Border" 
            Property="Background" 
            Value="WhiteSmoke" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="local:Window1.IsFirstTab" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Border" 
            Property="Background" 
            Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
```

This must help.

The same trick would work with last tab. Or you can have a number instead of bool as attached property.